# Checking Session[key] to null if I use form authentication

Tags: session, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC4 application. Where I am using Form-Authentication.
In that application I am using Session variables.
Do I need to check them for null values or it automatically check for Session.
And if it is null it is redirected to login page.

eg. If I am using like below it automatically redirect to my Login action

```
string lstrUserId=Context.Session["UserId"];
```

or do I need to check it manually

```
 if(Context.Session["UserId"] != null)
       RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
```

As far my knowledge session is maintain by the framework itself.

If so why I am getting null reference exception.

Answer (score 0):

Add `[Authorize]` attribute to your controllers.

Comment: I have used created a class `CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute` and used that.

Comment: @Shekhar it's okay BUT if you had any overriding made to this Custom class you have, it might not work well. just make sure you are still calling the `base` inherited methods in your overridden `virtual` methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using something like FormsAuthentication, this will be set to true if the user has a valid FormsAuthentication cookie on their machine (which you can add by using FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie).

Authorize attribute works by looking at HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated.

The code below is from the published Microsoft source code for **Authorize Attrubute**

```
 protected virtual bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext) {
    if (httpContext == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");
    } 

    IPrincipal user = httpContext.User; 
    if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated) { 
        return false;
    } 

    if (_usersSplit.Length > 0 && !_usersSplit.Contains(user.Identity.Name,StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
        return false;
    } 

    if (_rolesSplit.Length > 0 && !_rolesSplit.Any(user.IsInRole)) { 
        return false; 
    }

    return true;
}
```

[FormsAuthentication in details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.aspx)